# C# Windows Forms application showing background when opening new form

Tags: c#, forms, fullscreen

I am currently making a full-screen application in C# but I have a bit of a problem. I have a overview form which shows buttons. When you click a button it will open a new form. (Overview form and new form are both full-screen). The problem is when the new form opens it will show nothing for a second (It doesnt really look to good in a full screen application). So does anyone know how to fix this? You can find the code here:

Code for opening new form:

```
void NewForm(Form form)
{
    form.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(form_Closed);
    form.Show();
    Hide();
}

void form_Closed(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Show();
}
```

One of the opened forms:

```
public AdminPanelForm()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
     SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
     SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, true);
}

private void AdminPanelForm_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     List<User> users = User.GetAllUsers();
     foreach(User user in users)
     {
         ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(user.UserName);
         lvi.SubItems.Add(user.Role);
         listUsers.Items.Add(lvi);
     }
}

private void btnBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Close();
}
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Generally it's preferred to include code in your post.  While it's not explicitly required, links to off-site resources tend to go bad, and when it does, the question will be useless for other people with the same problem.  See Also: [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Allright changed it.

Comment: Call `form.BringToFront();` after `form.Show();`

Comment: Thanks for your reply @X-TECH. The solution was to put `form.Update()` because otherwise it opens with a delay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `form.Show()` add `form.Update()`. Otherwise, the real form redraw will be done with delay. It may be better to call `Hide` first.

Comment: Many thanks! Didn't know the answer could be that simple.